# Zigzag conversion

Tags: java, data-structures

Question is : The string "PAYPALISHIRING" is written in a zigzag pattern on a given number of rows like this: (you may want to display this pattern in a fixed font for better legibility)

```
P   A   H   N
A P L S I I G
Y   I   R
```

And then read line by line: "PAHNAPLSIIGYIR"

I have written below code, appearantly it works fine, but I might miss some corner cases. Could you help me to find all the corner cases for this question on my answer?

```
public static String zigZagConversion(String s , int rowNum){

    if (s == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    if (rowNum == 1){
        return s;
    }
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

    int step = 2 * rowNum - 2 ;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < rowNum ; i++){

        if( i == 0 || i == rowNum -1){

            for (int j = i ; j < s.length() ; j +=step){

                str.append(s.charAt(j));                    
            }               
        }

        else{

            int step2 = 2* (rowNum - i - 1);
            int step3 = step - step2;
            int k = i;
            boolean flag = true;

            while (k < s.length()){
                str.append(s.charAt(k));

                if(flag){                       
                    k += step2;
                    flag = false;
                }
                else{                       
                    k +=step3;
                   flag = false;
                }

            }               

        }
    }
return str.toString();      
}
```

Comment: You're looking for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JohnBollinger it would be good for  Code Review SE if it was fully working, or at least *mostly* working, passing most test cases. That's not the case (yet). The corrected version (using my answer below, for example), will be good indeed on Code Review, for further improvements, optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives incorrect output for `"PAYPALISHIRING", 4`

```
P     I    N
A   L S  I G
Y A   H R
P     I
```

So the correct answer should be `PINALSIGYAHRPI`.

But your program gives `PINALIGYAIHRNPI`:
an "S" is missing, one extra "I" and one extra "N".

Your revised version is still incorrect, it gives `PINALSIIGYAHNPI`.

The problem is in the `while` loop in the middle.
You need to alternate the step counting,
setting the `flag` on and off.
Your mistake was to only set it off once, and never back on again.

```
str.append(s.charAt(k));
if (flag) {
    k += step2;
    flag = false;
} else {
    k += step3;
    flag = true;
}
```

With this correction, I believe your solution is correct. (I also added a minor improvement there, extracting the common `str.append(s.charAt(k));` from the if-else branches.

Answer (score 1):

My solution on leetcode forum:
https://leetcode.com/problems/zigzag-conversion/discuss/549451/Java-Solution-O(n)-with-algorithm

The mathematic algorithm for zigzag is:

- originalDiff = numRows * 2 - 2;
- If -> 'currRow' equals First or last lines

  - use the originalDiff (numRows * 2 - 2)
- Else ->

  - For each new line:

    - upperDiff += 2,
    - lowerDiff -=2

Examples:

```
numRows =2 -> originalDiff = 2
PYAIHRN
APLSIIG

3 -> 4
P   A   H   N
A P L S I I G
Y   I   R

numRows = 4 -> originalDiff = 6
P    I    N
A  L S  I G
Y A  H R
P    I 

numRows = 5 -> originalDiff = 8
P    H   
A   SI   
Y  I R 
P L  I G  
A    N
*/
```

My solution:

```
class Solution {
    public String convert(String s, int numRows) {
        if(numRows == 1) {
            return s;
        }

        String newString = "";
        int originalDiff = numRows * 2 - 2;
        int diff = originalDiff;
        int upperDiff = 0;

        boolean isGoingDown = true;

        int currIndex = 0;
        int currRow = 0;
        int startingIndex = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

            System.out.println(currIndex);

            newString += s.charAt(currIndex);

            if(currRow == 0 || currRow == numRows - 1) {
                currIndex += originalDiff;
            } else { 
                if(isGoingDown) {
                    currIndex += diff;
                    isGoingDown = !isGoingDown;
                } else {
                    currIndex += upperDiff;
                    isGoingDown = !isGoingDown;
                }
            }

            if(currIndex >= s.length()) {
                currRow++;
                diff -= 2;
                upperDiff += 2;
                currIndex = currRow;
                isGoingDown = true;
            }
            if(currRow == numRows) {
                i = s.length();
            }
        }

        return newString;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Zigzag conversion from leetcode in Javascript

#### Solution

```
const zigzag = (str, num) => {
  if (num === 1) {
    return str;
  }
  let check = true;
  let result = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (i < str.length) {
    result.push([]);
    let j = 0;
    while (j < num) {
      if (check){
        result[result.length-1].push(str[i]);
        i++;
      } else {
        if (j == 0) {
          result[result.length-1].push(null);
        } else if (j === num-1) {
          result[result.length-1].unshift(null);
        } else {
          result[result.length-1].unshift(str[i]);
          i++;
        }
      }
      j++;
    }
    check = !check;
  }
  let zigzag = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < num; k++){
    for(let l = 0; l < result.length; l++) {
      zigzag.push(result[l][k]);
    }
  }
  return zigzag.join("");
}
```

#### Example Input

```
zigzag("ABCD", 3)
```

#### Output

```
ABDC
```

#### Run

https://repl.it/@VinitKhandelwal/zigzag-conversion-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Using HashMap

```
public String convert(String s, int numRows) {
    if (numRows == 1){
        return s;
    }
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    Map<Integer, StringBuilder> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        map.put(i,new StringBuilder());
    }
    int it = 0;
    boolean flip = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (flip) {
            if(it<s.length()){
                map.get(it).append(s.charAt(i));
                it++;
            }
        } else {
            map.get(it).append(s.charAt(i));
            it--;
        }
        if (it + 1 == numRows || it == 0)
            flip = !flip;

    }
    for (Map.Entry entry: map.entrySet()) {
        result.append(entry.getValue());
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is traversing the string in the same way it is said in the problem, it is better to make string array of size numrows and the rest is storing the string character as it is in the logic,

you can keep the index and when that index is 0 i.e at the starting then we have to go till the end of the row and then except for first and last row, every array will have diagonal element.

So after traversing till the end then assign index = numrows - 2 and save in the respective array string and decrease and do the same till index >0 and then again traverse till the end row, do this and when we reach the end of the string then break from the loop.

and then concate all the string of string array in a new res string.

```
class Solution {
    public String convert(String s, int n) {
    if(n==1 || n>=s.length())
        return s;
        String[] a = new String[n]; //string array
        int ind=0;    // index for the string array
        boolean flag=true;
        int cnt=0;   //to keep the counter till where we have traversed the string
        while(true && flag)
        {
            if(ind==0)
            {
                for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                {
                    a[i] += s.charAt(cnt);
                    cnt++;
                    if(cnt==s.length())
                    {
                        flag=false;
                        break;
                    }
                }                 // here it has reached the end so we assign here
                ind = n-2;
            }
            else if(ind>0 && ind<n && flag)
            {
                a[ind] += s.charAt(cnt);
                cnt++;
                if(cnt==s.length())
                    {
                        flag=false;
                        break;
                    }
                ind--;          // to move diagonally up
            }
        }
        String res = new String("");
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
            // System.out.println(a[i].substring(4));
            res += a[i].substring(4);
        }


        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the simple solution.

```
class Solution:
    def convert(self, s: str, numRows: int) -> str: 
        if numRows <= 1:
            return s
        
        res = ""
        p = numRows * 2 - 2
        
        temp = p
        for i in range(0,numRows):
            index = i
            flag = 0
            while index < len(s):
                res = res + s[index]
                if i == 0 or i == numRows-1:
                    index = index + p
                else:
                    if flag == 0:
                        index = index + temp
                        flag = 1
                    else:
                        index = index + p-temp
                        flag = 0
                        
            temp = temp - 2
            
        return res
```

Answer (score 0):

**zigzag-conversion Complete JavaScript-based solution**

> Created an Array of an array of row lengths. The main motive is to arrange characters in 2D array form and concat string row-wise.
> [image]

```
var convert = function(s, numRows) {
    let array =[],c=0,str='';
    for(let row =0; row<numRows ; row++) {
        array[row] = new Array();
    }  
    while(c < s.length) {
        for(let row =0; row<numRows ; row++) {
        if((row+1)%numRows ==0) {
            array[row].push(s[c]);
            c++;
            break;
        } else {
            array[row].push(s[c]);
            c++;
        } 
      }
      for(let rr = numRows-2 ; rr>0;rr--) {
          array[rr].push(s[c]);
          c++;
      }
    }
    for(let row =0; row<numRows ; row++) {
          for(let i=0;i<array[row].length;i++){
              if(array[row][i]){
                  str+=array[row][i]
              }
          }
      }
    return str
  };
  convert("PAYPALISHIRING",3)
```